# What is the time constant of RLC circuits

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

I am trying to understand how to analyze and understand the $RLC$ circuit. I know that in $RL$ and $RC$ circuits there is time constant $\tau$ wich determine how long it will take to $I_{(t)}$ decress to about $0.001I_0$. but what is the factor that determine it in $RLC$ circuits? is it the $Q$ factor?

Comment: The RLC circuit is a 2nd order system and so you have to be more specific about what you're looking for. Is the RLC circuit overdamped, critically damped, or underdamped?

Comment: underdamped is my main concept now.